# Use Azure API without service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Can I make API calls without using service principal? I want to make at least GET requests using my credentials instead of a service principal, using PowerShell. If it is possible with Postman, it's even better.

I am referring to management API - management.azure.com. Eg. I want to get all the details of a managed disk.

Comment: @DavidMakogon edited.

Comment: @JoyWang Thanks. I have yet to try it. I do use MFA. Will update you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that with your credential, try the powershell command [`Get-AzureRmDisk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/Get-AzureRmDisk?view=azurermps-6.13.0) below.
**Note**: If your account needs multi-factor authentication, you could not use this way.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -TenantId "<TenantId>"
Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -DiskName "<DiskName>"
```

If you want to call the api in the postman, Eg. get all the details of a managed disk, you could navigate to this link [Disks - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/get), click the `Try It` button, log in and copy the `Authorization` token. Then go to postman, follow the doc to specify the parameters what the api need and the `Authorization` token, then you will be able to call the api.

Smaple:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/{diskName}?api-version=2018-06-01
```

[image]