# How to access Azure REST APIs without a Service Principal?

Tags: azure, postman, azure-rest-api

How do I generate a bearer token for my personal identity, like the Microsoft web page does [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/factories/list?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) when you click **Try it** and log in with your personal credentials?

For example, I would like to generate the bearer token programmatically in a pre-request script in Postman.

**UPDATE:** *The below error happens in Postman if you don't remove "Bearer " from the token. See @BrunoLucasAzure answer.*

Also, I have tried to copy the bearer token manually from the Microsoft "Try It" page into Postman as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922300/use-azure-api-without-service-principal) and I get a 401:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "The access token is invalid."
    }
}
```

Before you say it, I realize that I would want a Service Principal for productionalized usage, but I shouldn't need one to explore the APIs via my own tool (e.g. Postman).

Answer (score 1):

How did you set your postman?
if you login into the "try" you should get this:
[image]

copy #1 and #2 like this. Dont copy the word bearer, only the token and under authorization select bearer token

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I must have had user error yesterday, because I thought I tried with and without "Bearer " prefix in the Token field.  I gave this an upvote because I am sure it will be helpful to someone, however I am still looking for a way to automate this step.